# Yii2 deploy using GitHub actions

Tags: github, deployment, yii2

I was using the following configuration to deploy Yii2 applications with GitHub actions:

```
name: Build and Deploy - DEV
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - development

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@master

      - name: Setup Enviroment
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: '7.2'

      - name: Install Packages
        run: composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

      - name: Deploy to Server
        uses: yiier/yii2-base-deploy@master
        with:
          user: github
          host: ${{ host }}
          path: ${{ path }}
          owner: github
        env:
          DEPLOY_KEY: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}
        
      - name: Apply migration
        run: php yii migrate --interactive=0
```

It worked quite well, but now is giving this error:

```
Current runner version: '2.285.1'
Operating System
Virtual Environment
Virtual Environment Provisioner
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
Secret source: Actions
Prepare workflow directory
Prepare all required actions
Getting action download info
Error: Unable to resolve action `yiier/yii2-base-deploy@master`, repository not found
```

Appears that `yiier/yii2-base-deploy@master` no longer existis.

Anyone knows a replacer?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this fork for you https://github.com/vityakut/yii2-base-deploy

Comment: Thanks @SiZE. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to SiZE comment i remember I had fork the original repo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).